# How can I add WFS layer URL in WPS request builder in GeoServer 2.17?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wps

I tried adding my layer URL under reference input type but no luck. I'm trying to create buffer.

[image: Screenshot of builder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `Buffer` operation is expecting a `Geometry` and you are providing a `FeatureCollection`. So you probably want to use the `vec:BufferFeatureCollection` process instead.

Comment: Cool let me check

Comment: Hi, but them how can I use the geometry from geoserver wfs url in the reference? (e.g. for JTS:area)

Comment: You can't a Geometry is a single object while a WFS returns a collection of features - maybe you need to ask a new question that describes what you are actually trying to do with the WPS